# Magento2.3 - Form messages not displaying

Tags: magento2, forms, magento2.3.1, messages

In my `Magento` website, no `Success/Error` message is displayed after submitting `Registration/Contact` form.

I have tested this both on my `custom theme` and default `luma` theme.

Message block exists in page html.

How can I fix this or find what causes it?

Comment: are you using messageManager (\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface) to show message?

Comment: @DimplePanchal If default magento registration/contact form use messageManager, then yes. I have this issue with the standard magento forms

Comment: ok let me check